# When would I choose IPTables over an Ambassador pattern for port forwarding?

Tags: docker, ports

In an environment of Secured [Virtual Private Clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_cloud), in a Cluster of [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) Containers, we have to setup some routes.

We can do that with the [Ambassador pattern](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/ambassador_pattern_linking/), which is simple and easy to maintain. (Docker does have some usage of IPTables under the hood - but from what I can see the Ambassador pattern uses socat, and not IPTables to achieve its forwarding.

We can setup [NAT](https://wiki.untangle.com/index.php/NAT_Rules) rules with [IPTables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) to achieve a similar goal.

My question is: **When would I choose IPTables over an Ambassador pattern for port forwarding?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iptables` will probably scale better than `socat` because `socat` runs completely in user space.  There's a common impression that `iptables` is hard to deal with, but I find it easier that most routers to fiddle with.  There are a number of `iptables` wrappers available to make it easier to handle.

If you're willing to accept the performance hit of running in user space then consider `haproxy` over `socat` because it is intended to run over longer periods and provides statistics, failover, SSL termination, and lots of other conveniences.

Comment: Great thinking - in terms of user maintainability - would you say that socat or iptables are more 'self-documenting' for other people to understand?

Comment: I'd say the configs for `haproxy` are easiest to follow.  Then `iptables` is likely to be used for more complex things than `socat` and easier to maintain.